# Why am I reminded I cannot ask a question within 20 minutes?

Tags: support, asking-questions

My reputation is less than 125. I did not ask a question 20 minutes ago. But the system reminds me I can only post questions every 20 minutes. What is the problem?

Comment: It could have been someone else at your location (eg. same IP address)

Comment: Unfortunately what @AndrewBarber suggests is probably what actually happened, the rate limit is enforced at an IP level as explained in [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/new-question-answer-rate-limits/), and the only solution is to earn 100+ reputation points.

Comment: @AndrewBarber thank you very much for asking my question. I do not know the mean that someone else at my location? Maybe he use the same ID with me? How could he?

Comment: You know, there are a couple things that look a *tiny bit* odd on your account, so I'm going to refrain from going further here.

Comment: @YannisRizos Thanks for your explaination. I am a new user. If i can not ask question, and no action here. How could i earn 100+ reputation points. I am worried about this.

Comment: @Curie - you can earn reputation by posting **answers**

Comment: @Curie - regarding your question about your location - are you accessing Stack Overflow from your work or are you using a proxy? If so then you'll share your IP address with other users who will be affecting you in this regard.

Comment: OP is in China, maybe a `GFW` tag is needed

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks for your advice. I should post answers if i know. I access Stack Overflow from my work, and did not use a proxy.

Comment: Can StackExchange turn on improved capture in such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 27 other users who've accessed the site from the same IP address as you. And as Yannis mentioned, these rate-limits are enforced at the IP level (since the intention is to prevent [Tupac-style abuse](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/new-question-answer-rate-limits/), limiting it by account alone wouldn't help).

You should be able to wait a bit and then post another question. Once you have over 100 reputation points, the limits are less strict.